# Redshift serverless client api call list_workgroups gets timedout in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint, amazon-redshift-serverless

I have a lambda function which uses below code to list redshift serverless workgroups.

```
client = boto3.client("redshift-serverless")
res = client.list_workgroups()
```

I have configured local subnets for lambda which does not have internet access. I have my vpc endpoints configured for local subnets.

My redshift provisioned cluster api describe_clusters() works fine. Does anyone know why I'm facing issue only for redshift serverless api calls.

Thanks

I tried to add full access to my redshift serverless and lambda security groups which did not work.

Comment: Hello, can you add more details about the issue you had? Maybe the error message and what 'did not work?'

Comment: AWS confirmed that for redshift-serverless boto3 api to work we need to add 0.0.0.0 route in the subnet route table. Creating VPC endpoint for redshift will not work.